# Did Fethullah Gülen "publicly boasted about his “soldiers” waiting for his orders to do whatever he directs them to do"?

Tags: politics, turkey

According to this [newsweek](http://europe.newsweek.com/michael-rubin-why-general-flynn-taking-erdogan-side-521633) article, retired lieutenant general of the US army and America's president elect Donald Trump's pick for national security advisor, Michael Flynn said:

> "Gülen portrays himself as a moderate, but he is in fact a radical Islamist. He has publicly boasted about his “soldiers” waiting for his orders to do whatever he directs them to do. If he were in reality a moderate, he would not be in exile, nor would he excite the animus of Recep Tayyip Erdogan and his government."

Is the claim that [Fethullah Gülen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fethullah_G%C3%BClen) "publicly boasted about his “soldiers” waiting for his orders to do whatever he directs them to do" true?

Comment: This seems to be the source? http://www.dailysabah.com/turkey/2016/09/10/gulen-threatens-turkey-in-new-video-says-his-sleeping-soldiers-are-waiting-for-orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary source of the claim is [this](http://thehill.com/blogs/pundits-blog/foreign-policy/305021-our-ally-turkey-is-in-crisis-and-needs-our-support) article written by Flynn. He wrote:

> Gülen portrays himself as a moderate, but he is in fact a radical Islamist. He has publicly boasted about his “soldiers” waiting for his orders to do whatever he directs them to do. If he were in reality a moderate, he would not be in exile, nor would he excite the animus of Recep Tayyip Erdoğan and his government.

And provided [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcIoRsSNyG4&feature=youtu.be) as evidence. According to the subtitles of the video, Gulen said:

> According to scientists, we have more than 10 billion ... these 10 billion cells in the brain are waiting for a command. To take action to think and reflect. Since Allah has put them in those positions, with many soldiers there as well. I think you can conquer many thing. But I think they are asleep now, yes asleep. Because they were not given duties or didn't face any difficulties.

Flynn interpreted this as public boasting by Gulen about his “soldiers waiting for his orders to do whatever he directs them to do."